# Connecting to VPN through a custom client

Tags: vpn

OK, here goes:

I have a CentOS server set up to accept PPTP connections and tunnel the users traffic through my server.

I am sharing this with my friends and family, and everytime they want to connect they have to go into control panel, and connect to the network manually. To set up the network, they go through a wizzard that Windows has to set up a new VPN connection for them, and they put in the IP address, username and password.

I wanted to make a really simple client for them to use. When it's first installed and they click "Connect", the program must make the new network (like they were going through the wizard), and every time after that just swap over to use the VPN network. If they click "Disconnect", it will go back to using their regular LAN network.

I would ideally like to code this in .NET, as that is where I have a lot of experience, but I have no idea where to start.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Maybe some code samples?

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. =]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, much easier to understand - thanks for the clarification!

At the risk of sounding like I'm an OpenVPN fanatic, look at [openvpn](http://www.openvpn.net), particularly the Access Server [here](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as.html).  I think you'll find it does exactly what you need.

OpenVPN is open source, so it's 100% code samples and as customizable as you like. (Be careful what you ask for! :-) )

Good luck!